# A strange insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I saw this ant-like insect in Brazil, close to Rio de Janeiro. It was around 2 cm long. I tried to  use google's search by image, but no luck. Does any one know the name of the species?

[image: Ant with a amber colored spot on it]

Comment: I would have though a [Polyrhachis](http://www.brisbaneinsects.com/brisbane_ants/golden_ant.htm) is you had found it in Australia but they don't seem to exist in Brazil. [Here is the list of ant species living in Brazil](http://antwiki.org/wiki/Brazil).

Comment: Its not an ant.

Comment: Possibly Mutillidae or a related family? (but beyond that I have no clue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insects like this are commonly called "velvet ants", but they are wasps, not ants. This insect is in the family *Mutillidae*, and it's called *Hopolocrates cephalotes*. 
(https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/629302-Hoplocrates-cephalotes/browse_photos)